# Datetime GMT format SQLITE query

Tags: sqlite, date, substr

I've imported some data into a sqlite database and I have two different time format

'2020-03-31T16:53:00' ISO FORMAT 8601

'Fri Apr 24 11:08:27 GMT+00:00 2021'

I need to generate a report by HOURS and for the format with T are correctly viewed but for the other format It doesn't show up data.

This is the query that generate the report :

```
select DISTINCT STRFTIME("%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00",DeviceDate) DeviceDate,
STRFTIME("%Y-%m-%d %H:59:59",DeviceDate) Date_End,sender,recipient, 
IIF(LENGTH(SUBSTR( media_filename,INSTR( media_filename,".") +1,
length( media_filename))) = 0, "msg", 
SUBSTR( media_filename,INSTR( media_filename,".") +1,
length( media_filename))) media_filename                       
from Messages rm where length(body) > 4
```

For the YYYY-MM-DD T HH:MM:SS time was correctly displayed without T, but the other type of data show up NULL...

Comment: All such rows have `GMT+00:00`?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's date functions work only with ISO formatted Text dates.

Update your table:

```
WITH cte(month, monthname) AS (
  VALUES ('01', 'Jan'), ('02', 'Feb'), ('03', 'Mar'), ('04', 'Apr'), 
         ('05', 'May'), ('06', 'Jun'), ('07', 'Jul'), ('08', 'Aug'), 
         ('09', 'Sep'), ('10', 'Oct'), ('11', 'Nov'), ('12', 'Dec')
)
UPDATE Messages
SET DeviceDate = SUBSTR(DeviceDate, -4) || '-' ||
                 (SELECT month FROM cte WHERE cte.monthname = SUBSTR(Messages.DeviceDate, 5, 3)) || '-' ||
                 SUBSTR(DeviceDate, 9, 11)
WHERE DeviceDate LIKE '___ ___ __ __:__:__ GMT+00:00 ____';
```

and your code will work.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dd00d4a72dc175e227b6deda653c766b).

Comment: I' have used a CASE SUBSTRING to solve my problem ...

`SELECT
    CASE SUBSTRING(DeviceDate,5,3)
         WHEN 'Jan' THEN TRIM(SUBSTRING(DeviceDate,LENGTH(DeviceDate)-3,4))||'-'||'01'||'-'||SUBSTRING(DeviceDate,9,2)||SUBSTRING(DeviceDate,11,4)||SUBSTRING(DeviceDate,15,3)||SUBSTRING(DeviceDate,18,2) `

Comment: @RedDot your query is too verbose.